# Turn.js - TypeError: parent.offset(...) is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am getting the following error when trying to run turn.js on a server. On my local machine via the browser it is working perfectly. My issue is occurring when I am trying to deploy it on a server.

I am using the same basic.js and basic.css code provided in the basic example folder. I have a server path to all the turn.js files in the framework. I only changed the path of the three files in the yepnope section to the server paths. The jquery and modernizr are referenced via the server. I can see that the all the js and css files are loaded in the browser from the server.

ERROR:

```
TypeError: parent.offset(...) is null
data.fwrapper = $('<div/>', divAtt(parent.offset().top, parent.offset().left)).
```

HTML CODE:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width = 500, user-scalable = no" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="flipbook-viewport">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="flipbook">
            <div> Turn.js </div>
                    <div> Page 1 </div>
                    <div> Page 2 </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function loadApp() {

    // Create the flipbook

    $('.flipbook').turn({
            // Width

            width:922,

            // Height

            height:600,

            // Elevation

            elevation: 50,

            // Enable gradients

            gradients: true,

            // Auto center this flipbook

            autoCenter: true

    });
}

// Load the HTML4 version if there's not CSS transform

yepnope({
    test : Modernizr.csstransforms,
    yep: ['/apps/chacha/components/content/flipbook/clientlibs/js/turn.js'],
    nope: ['/apps/chacha/components/content/flipbook/clientlibs/js/turn.html4.min.js'],
    both: ['/apps/chacha/components/content/flipbook/clientlibs/css/basic.css'],
    complete: loadApp
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```